# SSL Mixed Content but I can't find images on ftp

Tags: wordpress, ssl, mixed-content

I use WordPress, and I bought a theme from ThemeForest. Everything is great, but when I installed SSL I get insecure connection on my homepage.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://freindly-flowers.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://freindly-flowers.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/logo-watermark.png?id=6521'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
>
> (index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://freindly-flowers.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://freindly-flowers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/testimonials.jpg?id=7079'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

I have tried searching for those images in FTP, but they are not anywhere in FTP. What can I do and how can it show mixed content for images that are not even on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are there - http://freindly-flowers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/testimonials.jpg loaded for me. The problem is that your code is including http: without the s.

Navigate to that page and then right click somewhere and select "view Source" to see the source code. Search for http: in the source and you'll find all of the insecure requests. You may have hardcoded some image sources or copied database entries without updating urls, I really don't know, but using relative urls is one way to avoid this issue.

Comment: I understand, its clearly some image added by WPBakery Builder, in viewsource its showing vc.custom codes with a background-image proprety and this http images. I tried finding it in js_composer plugin files but I had no luck. Guess I just need to search it? its somewhere there?

Comment: Any chance you had the images uploaded and then enabled the SSL certificate? This site suggests removing the images and re-uploading them now with the SSL security active. https://qode.ticksy.com/ticket/1649488/

Comment: unfourtenetly yes, i first installed the theme and them installed the SSL. I still cant find where the images are.

Comment: Do you mean cant find where they are on the server or can't find them when you are editing the page? If it's the latter, did you look at the header and footer styles?

Comment: I can't find them neither on server or when im editing the page. I looked everywhere. Any chance you can take a look if you're available, I can send you admin login or ftp through email

Comment: Ive sended you email!

Comment: The broken image links have been removed. Cheers!